# How to scale overlay in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, draw

:)

does someone know how to scale overlays in python?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
I want this overlay here:

[image]

to this:

[image]

python code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Crosshair(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, windowSize=24, penWidth=2, opacity=40):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ws = windowSize
        self.resize(windowSize+1, windowSize+1)
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0,255))
        self.pen.setWidth(penWidth)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.move(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center() + QtCore.QPoint(1,1))
        self.opacity = opacity


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        ws = self.ws
        d = 241
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setOpacity(self.opacity)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        # painter.drawLine( x1,y1, x2,y2    )
        painter.drawLine(ws/2, 0,               ws/2, ws/2 - ws/d)   # Top
        painter.drawLine(ws/2, ws/2 + ws/d,     ws/2, ws)   # Bottom
        painter.drawLine(0, ws/2,               ws/2 - ws/d, ws/2)   # Left
        painter.drawLine(ws/2 + ws/d, ws/2,     ws, ws/2)   # Right

        # Drawing X on center (How to scale this here?)
        painter.drawLine(100,100,120.5,120.5)  # Top Left
        painter.drawLine(200, 50, 120.5, 120.5)  # Top Right
        painter.drawLine(0, 200, 120.5, 120.5)  # Bottom Left
        painter.drawLine(200, 200, 120.5, 120.5)  # Bottom Right




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = Crosshair(windowSize=241, penWidth=2.5, opacity=0.5)
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "Scale"? Can't you just compute the correct coordinates?

Comment: sorry im new in python, can you show me how to do it pls?

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with python, it's just basic geometry. Once you've got the coordinates from `ws`, you can use them to find diagonals.

Comment: thank you <3 umm... can you tell me how to do my overlay on top of everything?